# Automatically create links from a PDF to a specific page in another PDF

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I have a parent pdf with references to many "child" pdfs, let's call them Parent.pdf and ChildX.pdf. Parent is several hundred pages long, in the footnotes there will be multiple references to different pages of ChildX (for various values of X)

I need a way to automatically go through Parent.pdf's text, find the text like "see ChildX, page Y" and insert a link in Parent to page Y in ChildX, such that when the link is clicked ChildX opens at page Y. There are no bookmarks in ChildX but I can add them if needed. **What tool(s) can I use for this, and which is the simplest to use?**

(For the sake of the argument, let's suppose that references are consistently written as above, although this is not the case - separate problem)

I'm largely language- and tech-agnostic though anything that works on Windows is a plus. Research has turned up iText, ReportLab and PyPDF, but I'm not sure which one can insert links to a specific part of a different document, nor what their strengths and weaknesses are. Also if anyone can suggest bits of example code for this, it would be very welcome!

Thanks,

Comment: Questions that are primarily opinion-based are out-of-bounds for StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

You can search through the text and then add "remote go-to annotations". The search needs to use a regular expression for the format "see Child X, page Y". My company's products PDFOne .NET and PDFOne (for Java) both support text search based on regular expressions and also adding remote go-to annotations. I guess there are other products that can do the same.